# Correctly save "ç" character

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

When I run the project on my computer it saves the word correctly with "ç". But executing the same function on server the word is saved wrong, as `servi�o`.

I'm using Entity Framework Core and the column has `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` for collation.

I hope someone could give me a light, because I don't know what is happening.

Class:

```
public class BankSlip
{
     public string PayeeName { get; set; }
}
```

EF Class:

```
public static void Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<BankSlip> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("Boleto", "pagamento");
        entity.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        
        entity.Property(p => p.PayeeName).HasColumnName("NomeBeneficiario").HasMaxLength(120).HasDefaultValue("Some name").IsRequired();
    }
```

Comment: And the column type is `nvarchar`?

Comment: You'll have to post a repro.  That should work fine for either `varchar` or `nvarchar`.  eg `create table #t(t varchar(200) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI )
insert into #t(t) values(N'ç')
select * from #t`

Comment: "On the server" you mean the project is deployed and run on the server ? In that case I would say it's a server configuration, or IIS configuration that isn't right

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks

Comment: @GSerg Yes, the column type is nvarchar

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Do you think that the language of the OS could cause this? My computer is in PT-BR, and the server is in english

Comment: Ha ha, hard to say, but yes, this has happened to me many times for several different reasons. But most of the time, it was : Language of the server, Language configuration in IIS or others, It might even just be how the files are saved. I remember using encoding ANSI instead of UTF-8 or the other way around and it was the solution this one time... But I would place my bet on the server or iis

Comment: The column is `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` on the server also? Are you able to connect to the DB on the server in SSMS and check? Also, can you supply the EF Class containing the referenced column?

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity) may also be relevant. I see this note: _This feature is introduced in EF Core 5.0._

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr When I run locally it's pointed to the same database used by the project on server. I will update the question with the EF Class

Comment: As @CardiDeMonacoJr already suggested, the column might not be `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` on the server. If the databases' default collations are different on the server vs locally, whenever columns are created without specifying the collation explicitly they end up being different.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it! I changed the file encode to UTF8, deployed the project in the server and the character was saved correctly